# A text-to-speech software for French

Tags: windows, gratis, speech-synthesis, french

I have some french text, would like convert them to MP3 files to listen. Any text-to-speech software to recommend? I hope it's free and for Windows. Note: not necessarily to MP3, as long as it could convert to audio files, e.g. .wav, it's ok.

Comment: (1) Natural reader – free trial, various voices, limited to ½ hour for free version. Unlimited for paid version. (2) Dragon.  Note, both have lots of voices in various languages including French. (3) Foxit is a free pdf reader and can do also text-to-speech (in the View menu). However, you will need to find a French voice. RealSpeak Sophie (French) used to be free, but now I can’t find it. You might also want to consider a browser plugin.

Comment: @aparente001 seems none is free on converting to mp3? e.g. natural reader trial version could read, but to convert to mp3 need upgrade...

Comment: You might be able to record to Audacity (free) through some sort of streaming.

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of [Intelligent Speaker](https://intelligent-speaker.com) - extension for browser, we use the best available speech engine - Polly from Amazon.
[image: Intelligent Speaker]

You can get your podcast feed and grab m4a files (better than mp3 - better quality for smaller filesize).

Answer (score 1):

You can e.g. use the free [Balabolka](http://www.cross-plus-a.com/balabolka.htm) which can save as MP3. It's free and runs on Windows. It will detect the installed voices.

[image: Screenshot with English voice]

You'll need a French voice so that the text sounds proper. Using e.g. Microsoft Anna will not give good results. Nuance has French [voices](https://sites.fastspring.com/nextup/product/nuance) for ~ 40 €.